# angular controller multiple times

Tags: angularjs, sockets

I have a web page with angular in which I am using ngroute to redirect to 3 pages.

```
modulo_angular.config(function($routeProvider){
                    //config y defi de las rutas
      $routeProvider.when("/", {
          controller: "appUOM",
          controllerAs: "apuom",
          templateUrl: "home.html"
          })
          .when("/descargas", {
          controller: "appSocket",
          controllerAs: "apsocket",
          templateUrl: "descargas.html"
          })
          .when("/opciones", {
          controller: "appPhenomena",
          controllerAs: "apphen",
          templateUrl: "opciones.html"
          });
      });
```

I have 3 factories and 3 different controllers. Each factory is related to one controller so I can keep data even when page is changed.

In one page, "descargas", I have sockets to receive data from ym node.js server. This is the controller:

```
function controladorSocket($http, factoryController, socket){
  var vm = this;
  vm.mensajes = factoryController.getMensajes();
  socket.on('mensaje', function(data){
    console.log(data.message);
    factoryController.addMensaje(data.message);
  });
}
```

And this, is the socket factory:

```
modulo_angular.factory('socket', function ($rootScope) {
 var socket = io.connect();
return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {
        var args = arguments;
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
          callback.apply(socket, args);
        });
      });
    }
};
});
```

Each time I switch from descargas.html to another page and come back, I receive socket messages as much as changed I have done until that moment.

So I think my problem comes because my socket.on('mensaje'... function should go in another place to avoit this. But I don't don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to destroy the socket manually on page change:

```
function controladorSocket($http, factoryController, socket){
  var vm = this;
  vm.mensajes = factoryController.getMensajes();
  socket.on('mensaje', function(data){
    console.log(data.message);
    factoryController.addMensaje(data.message);
  });
  this.$on('$destroy', function(){
    //destroy socket
  });
}
```

Comment: I get this error: this.$on is not a function with your function